# Is it possible to attach metadata to a section / paragraph in Word?

Tags: ms-word, metadata

I have a MS Word document that I would like to index. It contains several paragraphs, each of them relating to a specific item.
I would like to store, into the document, the fact that a paragraph is linked to a specific item - but this link should not be visible (metadata).

Is there a way of doing this using Word (2003, 2007 or 2010) ?

There seems to be something around custom XML tags, but this is not available in newer versions of Word and I would prefer not to build upon it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unfortunately Paragraph.ID isn't persisted, and everything else tends to be visible, somehow, or rather easily destroyed. But how about inserting a hidden point bookmark, e.g. called _markern, where "n" is some kind of serial number, at the end of the para? You can keep a sequence number in a document Variable, and if you need to store more information, you can use a document variable name that's derivable from the bookmark name.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539889/is-it-possible-to-store-hidden-metadata-information-that-is-tied-to-a-specific-t