# Macro for dynamic contract generation

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Problem**

I need a way to generate a contract based on options. Ideally I envision this as a few checkboxes, and each checkbox removes certain paragraphs within the word form.

**Solution?**

Im best with python, and could generate a python script for this easily but would ideally like to keep this within Word itself so other users can use it. After some searching, I think its possible for a macro to do this, but information is quite scarce. The best I can find is:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44794-auto-create-format-word-document-based-check-2.html?s=7359f1b140059c571f6f068c6c8787ca

But I cant quite figure out how to modify this to what I want. Am I in the right direction? Is this possible via a macro or should I just do it in python instead?

Comment: My first idea is to copy the template containing all paragraphs into a new workbook, then show the dialog to select the paragraphs. With `For Each Paragraph in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs`  you can iterate over all paragraphs and remove those you do not want. Since you can not rely on paragraph id, use another way to add metadata to the text, some suggest to use `ContentControl` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547541/17017616), but using a special sequence of characters should also do it. Remove the paragraph with `.Range.Delete`.

Comment: Your request would be pretty easy to do with VBA and there are lots of code samples available for that language. Instead of leosch's idea of deleting the text, you can simply mark bookmarked paragraphs as hidden text, then the user can show or hide the text by checking or unchecking the box.

Comment: Using Word vba, you want to work with documents, not workbooks.

Comment: Look here: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/ http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/insert_content_with_content_controls.html